# How to pass array of promise without invoke them?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I try to pass array of axios (as promise) to a function. and when I call the method I need to execute those promises.

```js
const arrayOfAxios = [
  axios('https://api.github.com/')
]

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('before call promise');

  Promise.all(arrayOfAxios).then(res => {

   console.log({ res });
  });

}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js" integrity="sha256-bd8XIKzrtyJ1O5Sh3Xp3GiuMIzWC42ZekvrMMD4GxRg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In my code I can see that `https://api.github.com/` immediately. and not when I invoke the `promise.all`.

Did I do it wrong? there is another way to set array of promises and invoke them later? (I mean for an axios example)

Comment: Promises *are already executed*. You don't first create a Promise object and then "start" it. The process is that you first start an async operation, then you get a Promise.

Comment: Why not just passing urls? and executing them when you want...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Promises don't *run* anything, they just *observe* things that are running. So it's not that you don't want to invoke the promises, it's that you don't want to start the things they're observing.  When you call `axios` (or whatever), it's **already** started its process that the promise it returns observes.

If you don't want that process to start, don't call `axios` (etc.). For instance, you might put a function that calls it in the array instead, then call it when you're ready for it to start its work:

```
const arrayOfAxios = [
  () => axios('https://api.github.com/') // *** A function we haven't called yet
];

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('before call promise');

  Promise.all(arrayOfAxios.map(f => f())).then(res => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^ *** Calling the function(s)
   console.log({ res });
  });

}, 5000);
```

Or if you're doing the same operation on all of the entries in the array, store the information needed for that operation (such as the URLs or options objects for `axios`):

```
const arrayOfAxios = [
  'https://api.github.com/' // *** Just the information needed for the call
];

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('before call promise');

  Promise.all(arrayOfAxios.map(url => axios(url))).then(res => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ *** Making the calls
   console.log({ res });
  });

}, 5000);
```